# Pygame fails on KEYDOWN with Russian keyboard layout

Tags: pygame, keyboard, localization

When I press a keyboard button on a keyboard with a Russian layout, my application pygame game crashes with this message:

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\u0444' in position 40: ordinal not in range(128)

This is my code:

```
 event = pygame.event.poll()
 if event.type == KEYDOWN:
    print(event)
```

(I pressed the latin 'a' key.)

Pressing keys in the English layout works fine.

I tried changing the `event.type == KEYDOWN` to `event.type == KEYUP`: Everything works, but then I cannot access the `event.unicode` field to get the pressed key.

How do I get `KEYDOWN` events to work with any keyboard layout?

Python version **3.2**

Comment: [This general Python 2.7 resource](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html) for working with Unicode might have something useful. Have you tried [casting](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html#the-unicode-type) the problematic value to the unicode string type with `unicode(variable_goes_here)`?

Comment: I'm using 3.2 Python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved.
Way to get correct non ASCII code :

```
event = pygame.event.poll()
if event.type == KEYDOWN:
   print(event.unicode)
```

Answer (score 4):

The program is trying to convert a unicode wide character format into a standard ascii format. The code you are trying to convert is out of the available ASCII format range.

http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/444/index.htm

This is the code you are trying to convert, and ASCII only supports 128 different values, with extended ASCII supporting 256.

*edit* you need to use functions that support unicode characters, instead of standard or wide ASCII characters.